# Intersection of unit sphere and ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, spheres

The sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the ellipsoid $a x^2 + y^2 + b z^2 = 1$
are given where $b > 1 > a > 0$. We compute their intersection. It turns out that these are the points
$$r_{\pm\pm}  = \left(x, \pm\sqrt{1 - \alpha x^2}, \pm\sqrt{\beta}x\right)$$
where $\alpha = \frac{b - a}{b - 1}$, $\beta = \frac{1 - a}{b - 1}$ (hence $1 +\beta = \alpha$),
for $|x|\leq 1/\sqrt{\alpha}$. It turns out that these points lie on a two circles (e.g., the first is union of $r_{++}$ and $r_{-+}$ types of points), which becomes aparent if we rotate each of the circles around $y$-axis, so that it lies in the $yz$-plane (for each circle we need different rotation).

> Is there any *obvious* reason why the intersection consist of circles and not two ellipses (as one would naively expect) or even worse - some non-planar curves?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to distinguish what's *obvious* or not, but here's how you can think of it given a couple of preliminaries as *obvious*:

If you believe that the intersection has two connected components, and if you think that it's obvious that each of these lies on a distinguished hyperplane (affine subspace) of $\mathbb {R}^3$, then you can easily see that each must indeed be a circle since the intersection of a sphere with a hyperplane is always a circle (unless it is either empty or only a single points).

Put differently, how would you embed an ellipse in a sphere? You'd probably still pick a hyperplane on which the ellipse lies, right? But then the ellipse is automatically a circle.

Comment: Yeah, assuming that, e.g.,  $r_{++}\cup r_{-+}$ is planar, it is now _obvious_ that this must be a circle.